# d3.js path and tooltip issue

Tags: svg, d3.js

im new to this d3.js stuff and i'm willing to learn it, i'm doing a site and i need my path to be open at the end and i want to add some tooltips to it, i've done read a few documents over the web and none made sense in my code, can anyone shed some light into it please, thanks in advance!! :)

my code is the following, it generates two graphics:

```
function getDateX(day2)
{
    day = new String(day2);
    return new Date(day.substring(0, 4) + '-' + day.substring(4, 6) + '-' + day.substring(6, 8));
}

function plotData(id, data, type)
{
    var margin = {top: 40, right: 15, bottom: 30, left: 55},
        width = 455,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(data.length < 7 ? data.length : (data.length > 14 ? data.length / 5 : data.length / 3) ).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d/%m"));
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5);


    var area = d3.svg.area()    
        .x(function(d) { return x(getDateX(d.day)); })
        .y0(height)                 
        .y1(function(d) { return y( type == 'score' ? parseFloat(d.score) : d.good + d.neutral + d.bad)});


    var svg = d3.select("#" + id)
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.data(data);
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return getDateX(d.day); }));
    var min = d3.min(data, function(d) { return parseFloat(d.score); });

    if(min > 6)
        min = 6;
    else if(min > 1)
        min--;

    if(type == 'score')
        y.domain([min, 10]);
    else
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.good + d.neutral + d.bad; })]);

    svg.append("path").datum(data).attr("class", "area").attr("d", area);
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis);
}



var scores = 
[
<%
    boolean appendComma = false;
    for(MovieGrade grade : info.getGrades())
    {
        if(appendComma)
            out.print(",");
        else
            appendComma = true;
        out.print("{\"day\":" + grade.getDay() + ", \"good\":" + grade.getGood() + ", \"neutral\":" + grade.getNeutral() + ", \"bad\":" + grade.getBad() + ", \"score\":\"" + grade.getScore() + "\"}");
    }
%>
];


plotData('evolucao-score', scores, 'score');
plotData('evolucao-comments', scores, 'comments');
```

Comment: What's your actual question? StackOverflow is most helpful when you can clearly articulate a problem you're having and what you've tried already - big code dumps like this aren't likely to get any answers.

Comment: id like to make this code generate tooltips on my svgs, but theres no way i couldn't do it...

Comment: In order to get good answers: 1) Just include the code that's causing problems. 2) Clearly state what you're trying to do ("Add tooltips"). 3) Usually, show something you've tried ("I tried to add tooltips like ... but I got the error ... ").

Comment: You might also look at jQuery-powerTip, if you're willing to use jQuery